# Image masking tool to implement mask RCNN using python

Tags: faster-rcnn, annotation

I am trying to understand Mask RCNN.  For that I have to input image with mask in png format while building the model.

I try to follow the article present in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-custom-mask-rcnn-model-with-tensorflow-object-detection-952f5b0c7ab4) blog.

The blogger used [Pixel Annotation Tool](https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool).

I tried to follow her steps.  I downloaded all the requirements for this tool.  Like QT, Open CV, CMAKE and VS 2015 +

When I try to update the build script as mentioned [here](https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool/tree/master/scripts_to_build) for windows.  I am unable to find the make OpenCV build folder. I am in windows 10 with Python 3.7.

I also tried [Lear Tool](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/klaeser/software_image_annotation).  It didn't help me.

I tried VGG annotation tool.  I am able to create bounding boxes but unable to create mask in png format.

Can anyone suggest a tool for this activity.

I have posted the same in Stackoverflow. I thought of posting it here since its more relevant. I am deleting the question from stackoverflow.